# How to install Coq libraries without installation guide?

Tags: coq

Many Coq libraries on github does not provide install guides / etc. documentation. Maybe there are general way / ways to install such libraries? For example, x86proved https://github.com/nbenton/x86proved How to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell.  But as a rule of thumb, you should look for files of three different forms:

- `Make`
- `Makefile`
- `_CoqProject` (for recent developments)

Depending on these conditions, You can try one of the following solutions.

1. If there is a `Make` file, then you should read the documentation of the `coq_makefile` command.  For instance, typing the following sequence of commands will be meaningful, most of the time:

   `coq_makefile -f Make -o Makefile.coq`
   `make -f Makefile.coq`
   `make -f Makefile.coq install`
2. If there is already a file named F that has `makefile` as a substring, then I would try

   `make -f F`
   `make -f F install`
3. If there is a `_CoqProject` file, then follow the same instructions as 1/ above.
4. If none of the above cases applies, then I would try the following:

   `ls *.v > MyMake`
   `coq_Makefile -f MyMake -o Makefile.coq`

and then proceed as in case 1/ above.

You should also check whether your pet project is available in the [coq opam archive](https://coq.inria.fr/packages).  When this is the case [this repository](https://github.com/coq/opam-coq-archive.git) contains tested installation instructions, in a somewhat advanced syntax.  At the date of writing these lines, this does not apply for Nick Benton's `x86proved`.

I hope this helps.  I have not tried on Nick Benton's development, but it appears that the `README.txt` file says that the sources are in the `src` subdirectory.  In turn, the `src` subdirectory contains a `Makefile`, so I would proceed as indicated above.  Please keep us informed of your progress, your experience will be valuable for other developers.

Comment: coq_makefile -f Makefile -o Makefile.coq
make -f Makefile.coq
causes error "multiple target".

Comment: Please read carefully the line that contains `coq_makefile`  in my answer.  The file name after the `-f` option is `Make`, not `Makefile`.